# HTTP status 400 request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect Spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

I'm doing a simple todo list with spring mvc where it allows the user to add a task to the list. The problem lies with after filling the form, I got a HTTP 400 error description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. I suspect there is a null some where in the method addToDo ( post ).

Error

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
```

Controller in question

```
@Controller
public class ToDoController {

@Autowired
private ToDoService service;

// All date parameters displayed as mm/DD/yyyy
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/DD/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/list-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
// HttpSession allows access to the session
public String showToDo(ModelMap model,  HttpSession httpSession) {
    String user = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("name");
    model.addAttribute("todos", service.retrieveTodos(user));
    return "list-todos";
}

// redirect to update form
@RequestMapping(value = "/update-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUpdateForm(ModelMap model, @RequestParam int id) {
    // To work with command bean
    model.addAttribute("todo", service.retrieveTodo(id));
    model.clear();
    return "updateToDo";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update-todo", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitUpdate(ModelMap model, @Valid ToDo todo, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/update-todo";
    }
    service.updateToDo(todo);
    model.clear();
    return "redirect:/list-todo";
}

// Will be executed first
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddForm(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("todo", new ToDo());
    return "addToDo";
}


/*
 * Will be executed after form is submitted
 * @Valid ToDo - command bean from addToDo.jsp. 
 * @Valid to validate the information
 * @BindingResult showcases the result of the validation
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitAddForm(ModelMap model , @Valid ToDo todo,  HttpSession httpSession, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("running" + result);
    // If there is validation error , return to addToDos page for user to fix the error
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/showAddForm";
    }
    String user = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("name");
    
    service.addTodo(user, todo.getDescription(), todo.getTargetDate(), false);      
    // Clears the url e.g. name?=jyj123
    model.clear();
    // return to the url which executes the showToDO
    return "redirect:/list-todo";
}

    // delete to do entry
 @RequestMapping(value = "/delete-todo", method= RequestMethod.GET) 
 public String deleteToDo(ModelMap model, @RequestParam int id) { 
     service.deleteTodo(id);
     model.clear();
     return "redirect:/list-todo"; }
```

addToDo.jsp that contains the form

```html
<%@ include file = "common/header.jspf" %>
<%@ include file = "common/nav.jspf" %>
    <div class="container">
        <H1>Add your task!</H1>
        <!-- form:form spring MVC container form tag -->
        <!-- commandName is command obj -->
        <form:form method="POST" commandName="todo">
            <!-- fieldset used to group elements in a form. Box elements in one box -->
            <fieldset class="form-group">
            <!-- path links the variable in ToDo.java -->
                <form:label path="description">Description:</form:label> 
                    <!-- required validates nulll -->
                <form:input path="description" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" /> 
                <form:errors path="description" cssClass="text-warning" />
                </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                <form:label path="targetDate">Target Date</form:label> 
                <form:input path="targetDate" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" /> 
                    <form:errors path="targetDate" cssClass="text-warning" />
                    
            </fieldset>
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </form:form>
        </div>
    <%@ include file = "common/footer.jspf" %>
```

Comment: add action="/add-todo" in form attribute. 400 Bad Request means client error. It is not rechable to server.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. The commandName should do that function

Comment: Is there any more logging on the server?

Comment: @tgdavies not showing anymore on the page

Comment: Not on the page @Fenzox, in the log file which the server writes

Comment: @tgdavies I'm hitting a Spring Security error at the moment, will update this problem when I get past it.